# Implementing custom mse loss function in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function, mse

I am trying to implement a custom loss function on TensorFlow to calculate circular mean squared error loss.

I am taking the difference of true and predicted values, y and yPredict which are both vectors (1D). I am adding another variable 2*j*pi where j ranges from -20 to 20. However, there seems to a problem in computing this line of code.

```
err_matrix = tf.Variable(np.zeros((np.shape(yPredict)[0], np.shape(yPredict)[1], k.shape[0])))
```

Here is the error message:

```
ValueError: slice index 1 of dimension 1 out of bounds. for 'strided_slice' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [100,1,41], [2], [2], [2] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <0 1>, input[2] = <0 2>, input[3] = <1 1>.
```

This is the full function and the function call and how it is linked to the optimizer.

Function:

```
def wmse(yPredict,y):
    k = tf.constant(np.array(range(-20, 21)))
    err_matrix = tf.Variable(np.zeros((np.shape(yPredict)[0], np.shape(yPredict)[1], k.shape[0])))
    for j in range(1, k.shape[0]):
        err_matrix[:, j] += tf.subtract(tf.subtract(yPredict,y), tf.constant(2*j*tf.constant(np.pi)))
    errs = tf.reduce_min(err_matrix, axis=1)
    std_CNN_errors = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(errs)))
    return std_CNN_errors
```

Function Call:

```
cost_function = wmse(network_outputs, outputs)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-4).minimize(cost_function, var_list=tf.trainable_variables())
```

Could someone help me with this please? Thanks!

Comment: What is the shape of y and yPredict and why are they np arrays? Should they instead be tensors and if so, should you be using tf.shape?